# Show Columns from differents Datasets

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008, ssrs-2008-r2, ssrs-2012

I am designing a report and have some doubts.

Actually i have 2 dataset (A (MainDataSet) and B)

In the report I am showing columns from A and I would like to show columns from B (as a group). I have used LookUp function but it is only showing me only 1 column from B.

I would like to show every column. For that I tried to use LookUpSet but I dont want to join the result. I would like to get as a single column.

There is a relation between A to B, 1:m.

I hope you had understand it.

Many thanks.

Comment: Can you provide some examples of what each dataset looks like? You'll need a different solution depending on if your records are separated by columns or rows.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your table properties set the `DataSetName` as DataSet B, the one with your Player data. Then use a `Lookup` expression to get a single record from MainDataSet A, i.e. the team and country for that player that year.

The expression here joins the datasets by year and position, but you may need an extra field to make sure each player appears in the correct team.

```
=Lookup(Fields!YEAR.Value + Fields!PLAYER_POSITION.Value,
  Fields!YEAR.Value + Fields!POSITION.Value 
  Fields!COUNTRY.Value, "MainDataSet")
```

*(This assumes that your two datasets come from different Data Sources. If they have the same source, it's typically easier to include all your data in a single dataset.)*

Comment: I dont want a single record, I would like to obtain more than one value in a dynamic table.

Comment: By a 'dynamic table', do you mean a Matrix? This could result a table with each player as a separate column and each team/position as a row. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd207149(v=sql.110).aspx